# Can chrome extension download a webpage to the extension folder?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working on a url filtering chrome extension, I want to download a webpage to my extension folder so that extension can access it even without connection to my server. Is it doable?

Comment: What do you want to do with the downloaded web page?

Comment: Not possible. Keep it in the storage.

Comment: i want to use it as redirectUrl for blocked request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[woxxom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) provided the answer in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75211392/can-chrome-extension-download-a-webpage-to-the-extension-folder/75321170#comment132720605_75211392):

> Not possible. Keep it in the storage.